# Standalone installed Intel distribution as anaconda environment

Tags: python, anaconda

I have downloaded the standalone installer of the Intel Distribution for python. But how to add it as an anaconda environment or add the packages in it to the root environment in anaconda?

Comment: Welcome to SU! Are you sure that the two installations are compatible at all?

Comment: @NiayeshIsky How do I check the compatibility of the 2 installations?

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda is not meant to work with pre-existing installations of Python (as hinted at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27239565/7315159)). The whole point of Anaconda is to be a standalone installation of Python that doesn't interact with any other Python installations on its host machine.

It is possible to use the Intel Distribution for Python (IDP) as the Python distribution in Anaconda, but only if you install IDP using `conda` (as explained at [the official Intel page for using IDP with Anaconda](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-distribution-for-python-with-anaconda)). You can also use Intel packages with a non-Intel distribution of Python (which still has to be installed through conda), as explained on the same page.

So, you can't use your standalone IDP installation with Anaconda. Install IDP through Anaconda's conda using the following:

```
conda config --add channels intel
conda create -n idp intelpython3_core python=3
```

or, if you want the full IDP:

```
conda config --add channels intel
conda create -n idp intelpython3_full python=3
```

And activate the IDP environment in the usual way:

```
source activate idp (Linux/Unix)
```

or:

```
activate idp (Windows)
```

Then, you can install [other Intel packages](https://anaconda.org/intel/packages) into Anaconda in the usual way, e.g.:

```
conda install sympy
```